# i want to count number of even,number of odd in php

Tags: php, arrays, count

I want to count number of even,number of odd.If there 2 even ,i count only one even,If there 2 odd i count
only one number of odd

```
<?php 
$myarray = array(5,5,0,1,2,1,1,6,1);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) { 
  echo "Index ", $i, ", value ", $myarray[$i], ": ";

  if ($myarray[$i] % 2 == 0) {
    echo "even\n";
  }
  else {
    echo "odd\n";
  }
}
?>
```

input =[5,5,0,1,2,1,1,6,1]

```
output =  5 :1(total(5) odd one),
          1:2 (total(1) odd two)
```

Comment: Just tried the code(http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81839c8256b5ac60d99a8aa46633e396662afebb) and it outputs all the values.

Comment: i want to count total odd,total even

Comment: If 2 even i count 1 even,same as if there 2 odd i count 1 odd

Comment: Have you tried to add a counter to your code?

Comment: yes,,,but i faced problem

Comment: i want to count total odd,total even number

Comment: If 2 even number i count only 1 even,same as if there 2 odd number i count  only 1 odd

Comment: Update the code you have tried to the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two variables that keep track of your odds and evens when you loop through your array.

```
$my_array = array( 5, 5, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1 );
$odd = $even = 0;

foreach ( $my_array as $number ) {
    $number % 2 == 0 ? $even++ : $odd++;
}

printf( 'Odd: %s | Even: %s', $odd, $even );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$num = array(23,12,11,9,6,7,4,5,3);
$n=count($num);
$even = 0;        
$odd = 0;            
         
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        
        if ($num[$i] & 1 == 1)
            $odd ++ ;    
        else               
            $even ++ ;        
    }
 
    echo "Number of even elements = $even
        and Number of odd elements = $odd" ;    

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create counters `$evens` and `odds`. Then Loop through elements in array check if number is odd
using `Ternary Operator` `(condition) ? true : false;`, and `$num & 1` return true if number is `odd`.

```
$nums = array(5,5,0,1,2,1,1,6,1);
$odds = $evens = 0;
foreach ($nums as $num) {
     $num & 1 ? ++$odds : ++$evens;
}
echo "Odds: $odds, Evens: $evens"; //Odds: 6, Evens: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count only number of `odds`, Because If we count number of `Odds` in array, It would be easy to know number of `Evens` by subtract number of elements in array with number of `Odds`

```php
$nums = array(5,5,0,1,2,1,1,6,1);
$odds = 0;
foreach ($nums as $num) {
    $odds += $num % 2;
}
$evens = count($nums)-$odds;
echo "Odds: $odds, Evens: $evens"; //Odds: 6, Evens: 3
```